# Input box doesn't allow multiple dots

Tags: javascript, winforms, input, textbox

I want to know there is any code that user can't input multiple dots in same text box, like that:

> 0.0.01

If they entered 0.1 then its not allow to again enter any dots in input field.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking!

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Winforms, then just check in the TextChanged event. Simply check if the last character entered is a ".". If it is, and there is a second "." in the TextBox already, then you just delete the last dot.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

1. use onKeyPress event in javascript
2. count the no. of dots in the value
3. if no. of dots is more than one then set event.keyCode value to 8 (*key code for backspace*)